# How to Pass typed delegate to .Net code from Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to convert a C# method to .Net code and I'm having some trouble.  Here's the C# line

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, "{{(.+?)}}", new MatchEvaluator(match => values[match.Groups[1].Value].ToString()));
```

My first attempt looks like so:

```
$text = New-Object System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchEvaluator -ArgumentList @({$values[$args[0].Groups[1].Value].ToString()})
```

I obviously don't understand how to create delegates in Powershell, and I've been googling for the past hour.  Everything I come across seems to fail, so I'm sure I have a fundamental misunderstanding of what's going on.  I know MatchEvaluator is itself a delegate type and I think the issue is I don't know how to create delegates from powershell scriptblocks.  I keep getting exceptions complaining the method paramenter is null, but I know for a fact that what I'm passing to it isn't null, so I'm lost.

Can anyone help out here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create delegate by casting to delegate type:

```powershell
$Delegate=[System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchEvaluator]{$values[$args[0].Groups[1].Value].ToString()}
```

But in many cases you can just pass `ScriptBlock` into method:

```powershell
$text=[Regex]::Replace($text, "{{(.+?)}}", {$values[$args[0].Groups[1].Value].ToString()})
```